# Evalutating $\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} (x+1)^k - (x)^k$ , given $0<k<1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, polynomials, limits-without-lhopital

I Tried evaluating as follows but got stuck with the uncertainty $(  0·\infty  ) $

***What I did was :***

$\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} (x+1)^k - (x)^k = \lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} (x)^k·(\frac{(x+1)^k}{(x)^k} - 1)  = \lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} (x)^k·((\frac{x+1}{x})^k - 1) = $
$\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} (x)^k·((1+\frac{1}{x})^k - 1) $

$\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} (x)^k·(e^{ln(1+\frac{1}{x})^k} - 1)  = (e^{k·ln(\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})} - 1) ·\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} (x)^k = (e^{k·ln(1)} - 1) ·\infty $ = $(e^{0} - 1) ·\infty  = (1 - 1) ·\infty $ = \

⇒ **$0 ·\infty $**

*( I Also Tried using the Squeeze theorem but all upper functions I tried went to $\infty$  )*

➔ Using $k=\frac{1}{2}$ and then $\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} \sqrt{(x+1)} - \sqrt{(x)}$ :

I found that  $\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)} + \sqrt{(x)}}$ = $\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\infty} = 0$ ,

**However** , I'm struggling to do the same algorithm with  $\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} \sqrt[q]{(x+1)} - \sqrt[q]{(x)}$ : Assuming $k=\frac{1}{q} $ ; $q \in (\mathbb{R}^+/ 0)$

*(meaning  $\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} (x+1)^k - (x)^k$  = $\lim \limits_{ x \to \infty} \sqrt[q]{(x+1)} - \sqrt[q]{(x)}$)*

**I would love to get some help on how to evalutate the limit !**

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem?

Comment: By the mean value theorem $$
k(x + 1)^{k - 1}  \le (x + 1)^k  - x^k  \le kx^{k - 1} 
$$ for $x\geq 1$ and $0<k<1$.

Comment: @Gary Any Chance you can further explain what you wrote , I know $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$ but I'm not sure I understand the inequalities you mentioned

Comment: @Losh_EE Use it with $f(x)=x^k$, $a=x$, $b=x+1$. To get the inequality note that $f'$ is decreasing and $x<c<x+1$.

Comment: @Gary That is an answer not a little comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rewrite the expression and use L'Hôpital's rule:

$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left((x+1)^k-x^k\right)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{(1+1/x)^k-1}{1/x^k}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{(-k/x^2)(1+1/x)^{k-1}}{-k x^{-k-1}}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}(x+1)^{k-1} = 0
$$

Comment: Thank you for the help !

Is there any way we can do this without using L'Hôpital's rule ?

Comment: You can try playing around with the generalized binomial:
$$
(x+1)^k = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \binom{k}{r} x^{k-r} = x^{k} \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{k}{r} x^{-r}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use Taylor polynomial:  as $h \to 0$, we have $(1+h)^k = 1+kh+o(h)$.
As $x\to\infty$,
$$
(x+1)^k = x^k\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^k = x^k\left(1+\frac{k}{x}+o(1/x)\right) = x^k+kx^{k-1}+o(x^{k-1})
\\
(x+1)^k - x^k = kx^{k-1}+o(x^{k-1})
$$
Now $k<1$ so $k-1 < 0$ and thus $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{k-1} = 0$.
Conclude
$$
(x+1)^k - x^k \to 0\quad\text{ as }x\to\infty
$$
or more pricisely
$$
(x+1)^k - x^k \sim kx^{k-1}\quad\text{ as }x\to\infty
$$
Example:
$$
\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x} \sim \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\quad\text{ as }x\to\infty
$$